# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Moving a web project from test enviroment to the web server made this error occur whenever tehre's an attempt to open a connection to the sql server.

We can insert and read data from sql server management studio.

We're suspecting that the error is created from a bad connection string or from the sql server using integrated security, but haven't been able to confirm that.

the connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DSVUShort" connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;database=NS_Survey; integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" />
</connectionStrings>
```

where it is used

```
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DSVUShort"].ToString());
Connection.Open() // pops the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

causes this error is connectionString in webConfig
Set connectionString in webConfig.
name of connectionStrin in webConfig and code behind must be same.

in web.config:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DSVUShort" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
```

in code:

```
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DSVUShort"].ToString());  
Connection.Open();
```

[image]

Comment: where and why did AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf come from?

Comment: Visual studio: In server explorer right click on Database.mdf and click on properties, then in properties window copy the connectionStrin and paste in connectionString in web.config

Comment: Had to change the security from windows authentication to a newly created user in the sql server, but it works now. Thanks for helping