# Connect local database mdf Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I have created a mdf database from visual studio 2013 and stored some informations in the table.

My problem is I can`t connect to my local database and select informations from table.
This is my code for connect:

```
string con = "Data Source=intrebari.mdf;Integrated Security=True;";

string queryString = "Select * FROM dbo.intrebari"; //update as you feel fit of course for insert/update etc

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    data = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(data);
    MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());

    connection.Close();
}
```

And the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

I already unblocked 1433 port with firewall but no succes. Here is a print to my visual studio work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHCK9.jpg

Comment: I think you might find some help here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file

Basically, you need to attach the MDF file to a SQL Server instance to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly use database file. You have to access it through DB server. Update your query string, you can find the proper connection strings [Here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). If you don't have Management studio installed, you can use the SQLExpress instance installed by default in MS STUDIO, the connection string is [HERE](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/) .

Comment: Something like this?             string con = "Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\vreisafiiiliardar\vreisafiiiliardar\intrebari.mdf;Database=intrebari;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";

Comment: Seems I have some connection problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gain7tomvgktepx/Screenshot%202014-01-15%2013.53.14.png

Comment: Try this link,note the path given there to the mdf file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443625/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne