# ASP.net unable to attach file as database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a data entry form for a database using C# and ASP.net in Visual Studio 2013. What I'm trying to build is a form that would allow me to enter the results for Nintendo Power Magazine's Top 30 poll into a table in the database.

The plan for the page in question is to have a GridView so I can see what results that I've already entered, and a FormView which will be used for the actual data entry. To make the process simpler I'm the issue and game through a drop-down menu, and to avoid confusing "Duck Tales" for the NES and "Duck Tales" for the Game Boy, I've set up an additional drop-down menu to select what system a game has been released on. The results of that menu, in turn, will determine what games will be in the "Games" drop down list.

So, I've almost finished putting this form together - however, I'm running into a problem when testing the form. When I go to select a system from the drop-down menu, I get this error message:

> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\TEST\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\NPPollDataEntry\App_Data\aspnet-NPPollDataEntry-14ef47ad-43d0-4a7d-b1c9-de351dbca3d5.mdf' as database 'aspnet-NPPollDataEntry-14ef47ad-43d0-4a7d-b1c9-de351dbca3d5'.

What am I doing wrong?

Form page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ResultsEntryForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="ResultsEntryForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="ResultsDataEntryForm" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="PollResultsDataSource" 
            AllowSorting="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Issue_Date" HeaderText="Issue_Date" 
                    SortExpression="Issue_Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Platform_Type" HeaderText="Platform_Type" 
                    SortExpression="Platform_Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Element_Title" HeaderText="Element_Title" 
                    SortExpression="Element_Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Poll_Score" HeaderText="Poll_Score" 
                    SortExpression="Poll_Score" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:FormView ID="ResultsFormView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            DataSourceID="PollResultsDataSource">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                Issue_Date:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="IssueDateDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    DataSourceID="IssueDateDropDownDataSource" DataTextField="Issue_Date" 
                    DataValueField="Issue_ID">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                Platform_Type:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="PlatformDropDownList" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="PlatformDropDownDataSource" DataTextField="Platform_Type" 
                    DataValueField="Platform_ID" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="PlatformDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                Element_Title:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="TitleDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                Poll_Score:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                Issue_Date:
                <asp:Label ID="Issue_DateLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Issue_Date") %>' />
                <br />
                Platform_Type:
                <asp:Label ID="Platform_TypeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Platform_Type") %>' />
                <br />
                Element_Title:
                <asp:Label ID="Element_TitleLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Element_Title") %>' />
                <br />
                Poll_Score:
                <asp:Label ID="Poll_ScoreLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Poll_Score") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="New" Text="New" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PollResultsDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NintendoPowerPollConnectionString %>" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Poll_Results(Issue_ID, Element_Group_ID, Poll_Score) VALUES (@Issue_ID, @Element_Group_ID, @Poll_Score)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT NintendoPowerIssue.Issue_Date, na_lkpPlatformTypes.Platform_Type, na_Games.Element_Title, Poll_Results.Poll_Score 
            FROM Poll_Results INNER JOIN NintendoPowerIssue ON Poll_Results.Issue_ID = NintendoPowerIssue.Issue_ID 
            INNER JOIN na_Games ON Poll_Results.Element_Group_ID = na_Games.Element_Group_ID 
            INNER JOIN na_lkpPlatformTypes ON na_Games.Platform_ID = na_lkpPlatformTypes.Platform_ID" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Poll_Results SET Poll_Score = @Poll_Score 
            FROM Poll_Results 
            INNER JOIN na_Games ON Poll_Results.Element_Group_ID = na_Games.Element_Group_ID 
            INNER JOIN NintendoPowerIssue ON Poll_Results.Issue_ID = NintendoPowerIssue.Issue_ID 
            WHERE (Poll_Results.Issue_ID = @Issue_ID) AND (Poll_Results.Element_Group_ID = @Element_Group_ID)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Issue_ID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Element_Group_ID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Poll_Score" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Poll_Score" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Issue_ID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Element_Group_ID" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="IssueDateDropDownDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NintendoPowerPollConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Issue_ID], [Issue_Date] FROM [NintendoPowerIssue]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PlatformDropDownDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NintendoPowerPollConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Platform_ID], [Platform_Type] FROM [na_lkpPlatformTypes]" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Back Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class ResultsEntryForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private DataTable BindDropDownList(string field)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT [Element_Group_ID], [Element_Title] FROM [na_Games] WHERE ([Platform_ID] = @Platform_ID)";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform_ID", field);
            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Write(ex.Message + ("<br />") + ex.Source);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return dt;
    }
    protected void PlatformDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)sender;
        FormView fv = (FormView)ddl1.NamingContainer;
        if (fv != null)
        {
            DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)fv.FindControl("TitleDropDownList");
            {
                DataTable dt = BindDropDownList(ddl1.SelectedItem.Value);
                ddl2.DataTextField = "Field1";
                ddl2.DataValueField = "Field2";
                ddl2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps it's a security issue? Under what context is the site running? Make sure the application pool user has full access to the database file

Comment: Also. Try giving the database a more friendly name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be the same as in this question:

[Connect local database mdf Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136553/connect-local-database-mdf-visual-studio)

MDF files need to be attached to a sql server instance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've got it attached to a sql server instance.

Answer (score 0):

- Open `Developer Command Propmpt for VisualStudio`
- Run commands:

  - `sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0`
  - `sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0`

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16339164/440611).